# Excel VBA: Is it possible to retrieve a users windows network password via VBA?

Tags: windows, oracle, vba, excel, passwords

I am currently working with an Oracle database that doesn't work with a Trusted Connection as the SQL database it is replacing did. The database requires a username and password to be entered for every query, which is run multiple times a day by multiple users. IT, as would be expected, require each user to login under their own credentials. The password needs to be updated every thirty days, as does their windows login password. Therefore it's impractical/unsecure to save a password within the connection string. The best solution I have so far is:

```
sConnectionString = "ODBC;DSN=" & sDatabaseName & ";UID=" & (Environ$("Username")) & ";PWD=" & sPassword
```

Where sPassword is set upon the user typing their password into a range, the value is then stored in the variable and cleared from the range. This should allow them to enter the password once each time they open the sheet.

However, as a number of the users are 'set in their ways' I would like to be able to pull their windows password into a variable and pass it to the database. I appreciate this is unlikely but I wonder if there is a way to retrieve the password without being able to see the value?

Comment: VBA does not have access to the user's password, nor for security purposes should it.

Comment: Passwords are generally a one-way street, you can't "read" them from a file or recordset - otherwise they would be redundant. Even if you could, VBA would never be powerful enough to achieve this.

Comment: @MacroMan, if the password was stored in a file or recordset, VBA would certainly be "powerful enough to achieve" it.  The issue is that the password is not available.

Comment: @lfrandom I get how my comment was misconstrued reading it back - but I wasn't implying that VBA can't read from a file or recordset haha! I meant that if there was a way to programmatically penetrate the OS to retrieve the password, you couldn't do it with VBA as it's rather encapsulated in the Office model and generally can't interact with the OS at the level.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected. I was just living in hope that it may be available in some encrypted form.

Comment: I don't know if your users are comfortable with it, but you could store the password after they enter it in the workbook?  Perhaps on a veryhidden sheet.  That's still rather insecure though, so you must evaluate trade-offs.  Then it could try to read from that range when connecting and so they would only have to do it the first time.

Comment: Do you have an MS-SQL Server running in your network? Then you could setup a Linked-Server Connection between the SQL and Oracle server and get the data from the MS-SQL server with pass-through-authentication. The password for the linked-server connection would never expire and could be extremely complex.

Comment: @Soulfire This is one of the solutions I am considering now. This is for read-only access to the database in any case. I would then password protect the VBA code. The biggest problem I have is with users who don't want to provide passwords to the spreadsheet and don't want to provide passwords to the ODBC query client... but do want the data. Hard to please some.

Comment: @Ralph Unfortunately I don't, that I'm aware of, and it sounds like a solution I may not be able to implement due to access/skill. Appreciate the suggestion though.